# Create the button's action with glade

Tags: bash, interface

I used `linux` `glade` to create interfaces of a bash script but I can not configure the button's actions

the first interface asks the user to choose the type of the query. When they click the button apply it leads him to the second interface to enter his query.

And when hi click ok the bash script is generated automaticaly.
That's all what i try to do.
actually the 1 and the 2 line in the bash script was replaced by the second interface.

[image: this is the first interface]

[image: and this is the second]

I want to perform an action that will allow us to go from the first to the second interface by clicking apply.

And another action that will allow to execute my requete.sh file by clicking ok in the second interface

and this is the code:

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p "saisir votre requete: "  req
printf "%s\n" "$req" > t1.txt

sed -e 's/[;,()'\'']/ /g;s/  */ /g' t1.txt > t.txt

tr -s '[[:blank:]]' '\n' < t.txt |
  while IFS= read -r word; do
      if ! [[ "$word" =~ $(echo ^\($(paste -sd'|' ./req.txt)\)$) ]]; then

      var=$(base64 <<< $word)
      sed -i -e "s/$word/$var/g" t1.txt
    fi

  done

cat 't1.txt' > requete.sql

scp requete.sql cloud1@192.168.190.128:/home/cloud1

#Conection to the Server
ssh cloud1@192.168.190.128 '/home/cloud1/Cloud-Serv'
```

and this is the xml code for the 2 interface

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkDialog" id="SecondScreen">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">My second screen</property>
    <property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
      <object class="GtkBox" id="dialog-vbox2">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
        <child internal-child="action_area">
          <object class="GtkButtonBox" id="dialog-action_area2">
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="layout_style">end</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="back_button">
                <property name="label">gtk-go-back</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">True</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_stock">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="ok_button">
                <property name="label">gtk-ok</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">True</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_stock">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="canc_button">
                <property name="label">gtk-cancel</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">True</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_stock">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">2</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="pack_type">end</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="menubar2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem5">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_File</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu4">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem11">
                        <property name="label">gtk-new</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem12">
                        <property name="label">gtk-open</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem13">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem14">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save-as</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkSeparatorMenuItem" id="separatormenuitem2">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem15">
                        <property name="label">gtk-quit</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem6">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Edit</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu5">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem16">
                        <property name="label">gtk-cut</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem17">
                        <property name="label">gtk-copy</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem18">
                        <property name="label">gtk-paste</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem19">
                        <property name="label">gtk-delete</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem7">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_View</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem8">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Help</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu6">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem20">
                        <property name="label">gtk-about</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="padding">1</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTextView" id="textview1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="padding">20</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAction" id="action1"/>
  <object class="GtkDialog" id="FirstScreen">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">My first Box</property>
    <property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
      <object class="GtkBox" id="dialog-vbox1">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
        <child internal-child="action_area">
          <object class="GtkButtonBox" id="dialog-action_area1">
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="layout_style">end</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="app_button">
                <property name="label">gtk-apply</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">True</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_stock">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="quit_button">
                <property name="label">gtk-quit</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">True</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_stock">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="pack_type">end</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="menubar1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_File</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu1">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem1">
                        <property name="label">gtk-new</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem2">
                        <property name="label">gtk-open</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem3">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem4">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save-as</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkSeparatorMenuItem" id="separatormenuitem1">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem5">
                        <property name="label">gtk-quit</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Edit</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu2">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem6">
                        <property name="label">gtk-cut</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem7">
                        <property name="label">gtk-copy</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem8">
                        <property name="label">gtk-paste</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem9">
                        <property name="label">gtk-delete</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem3">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_View</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem4">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Help</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu3">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem10">
                        <property name="label">gtk-about</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="padding">1</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="l1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="ypad">10</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Please choose your query type</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkRadioButton" id="rb1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Select</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">True</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">False</property>
            <property name="xalign">0</property>
            <property name="active">True</property>
            <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="padding">5</property>
            <property name="position">3</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkRadioButton" id="rb2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Others</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">True</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">False</property>
            <property name="xalign">0</property>
            <property name="active">True</property>
            <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="padding">5</property>
            <property name="position">4</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: We can't help if you don't show us your code. Please [edit] your question and include your script.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Where's the glade code? That's just a simple script. You are asking about the glade code so that's what we need to see.

Comment: but this is the problem i don't now how to generate the glade code. i create the two interface manually

Comment: Umm. OK. You said "I used" which means that you have already done so. In that case, [edit] your question and explain where you want the dialogs to appear. What should be in the dialogs? How is that connected to your script? When should the second screen appear and what should that contain?